# How to interact with USB device serially when it does not have a COM port?

Tags: windows, windows-10, com

I'm attaching a device to my computer that needs to interact through a serial interface.  THe device when attached just shows up as a "USB Test and Measurement Device" in device manager as shown [image].  I have some existing software that interacts with the device serially and identifies it as: USB0::0x1AB1::0x0E11::DP8D204400270::INSTR.  However, I have been unable to interact with the device using my own software.  Is there a way to interact with it serially directly as is, or is there a way  to force it to attach to a COM port for regular Serial interaction?

Answer (score 1):

Most likely, the program is using a completely custom USB-level protocol to talk to the device – it's accessing the device through [WinUSB](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/usbcon/winusb) / [libusb](https://libusb.info/) and performing custom USB requests and transfers.

This is often done for several reasons, such as not requiring OS-wide driver installation (instead the app itself contains the necessary knowledge) or avoiding the overhead of *emulating* a serial port when the actual communication isn't actually very serial-like. For example, the device might have separate USB 'endpoints' for control vs bulk data transfer.

Comment: Thanks for helping, a couple things here.  The program isn't using a completely custom protocol.  It's just a serial link through USB.  I have access to the data and the commands are a format called SCPI, which requires just a serial text link.  WinUSB/libusb might be used, I'm not sure, but I can also connect to it with a python script using the pyvisa library so it's not a proprietary interface